# Creating a DataFrame containing instances of a case class with integer attributes

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Spark fails to convert a sequence of such instances to a DataFrame/Dataset, which is not a great developer experience.

Is this a bug or an expected feature?

Consider an example:

```scala
import spark.implicits._
case class Test(`9`: Double)
```

This fails:

```scala
val failingTest = Seq(Test(9.0)).toDF()
```

This works fine:

```scala
val successfulTest = Seq(9.0).toDF("9").as[Test]
successfulTest.show()
```

[image: Zeppelin]

Comment: I think you are giving symbol(`) in the case class variable name so it is giving you error as it cannot parse it properly.

Comment: No, the problem is not in the attribute naming, since such case classes are valid in Scala. Not sure why Spark has to fail on this. I had to create a DataFrame from JSON instead to overcome this issue

Answer (score 0):

If you see the prerequisites of declaring a variable and how you name them, then how you are specifying a variable name is not allowed.

`The variable name must start with a letter and cannot begin with a number or other characters`

Just change your case class to use string variable name without symbol as below and it should work.

```
import spark.implicits._
case class Test(Id: Double)

val failingTest = Seq(Test(9.0)).toDS()
```

The above line of code would give you a dataset of Test as below :

`failingTest: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[Test] = [Id: double]`

```
val failingTest1 = Seq(test).toDF()
```

The above line would give you a Dataset of Row which is DataFrame as below:

`failingTest1: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [Id: double]`

It is giving you error because you are not providing the name in proper format.
You could also consider it as bug as it is not giving you error when you create a case class which I think it should have done.

Your code would also work if you just remove the value 9 and use any character as below:

```
import spark.implicits._
case class Test1(`i`: Double)
val failingTest = Seq(Test1(9.0)).toDF()
```

Comment: Still, such case classes are valid in Scala, even though they are not valid in Java. Why suffer from limitations of Java anyway?